# How to sentence embed from gensim Word2Vec embedding vectors?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec

I have a `pandas` dataframe containing descriptions. I would like to cluster descriptions based on meanings usign `CBOW`. My challenge for now is to document embed each row into equal dimensions vectors. At first I am training the word vectors using `gensim` as so:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

vocab = pd.concat((df['description'], df['more_description']))
model = Word2Vec(sentences=vocab, size=100, window=10, min_count=3, workers=4, sg=0)
```

I am however a bit confused now on how to replace the full sentences from my `df` with document vectors of equal dimensions.

For now, my workaround is repacing each word in each row with a vector then applying PCA dimentinality reduction to bring each vector to similar dimensions. Is there a better way of doing this though `gensim`, so that I could say something like this:

```
df['description'].apply(model.vectorize)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for sentence embedding. There are a lot ways of generating sentence embedding from word embeddings. You may find this useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286579/how-to-train-sentence-paragraph-document-embeddings